# I just don’t understand this wrapper parameters' workings?

Tags: python, wrapper

```
# This version only accepts one argument
# def shout(fn):
#     def wrapper(name):
#         return fn(name).upper()
#     return wrapper

# This version works with any number of args
def shout(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs).upper()
    return wrapper

@shout
def greet(name):
    return f"Hi, I'm {name}."

@shout
def order(main, side):
    return f"Hi, I'd like the {main}, with a side of {side}, please."

@shout
def lol():
    return "lol"

print(greet("todd"))
print(order(side="burger", main="fries"))
print(lol())
```

In the above code,

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

print(f"abc is {fn.__name__}")

    return fn(*args, **kwargs).upper()

    return wrapper
```

When wrapper functions executed, how does it knows the value of arguments which are to be assigned to , * args and **kwargs. We have not defined the values of arguments here, but instead func is given the parameters.

```
side="burger", main="fries".

**kwargs open up the dictionary but when did we defined such dictionary?
```

How does side="burger", main="fries" are set as arguments of wrapper function and Why are they being assigned to args and kwargs ?
Why are arguments given to fync being assigned to parameters of wrapper function?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Answer (score 0):

They are set when you call the function. When you call the wrapper, all positional arguments are packed together into `args` and all keyword arguments are put into `kwargs`, which are then unpacked and passed to the wrapped function.

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```py
order(side="burger", main="fries")
```

You are actually calling `wrapper()` with those parameters.

This is the time at which `**kwargs` is assigned.

`wrapper()` then goes on to call your actual function `order()` with `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: Why the wrapper function is called with those parameters?

Comment: Because `@shout; def order(...)` means: `order = shout(order)` which means that now `order` refers to `wrapper` which is returned from `shout()`.

Comment: I mean why  order(side="burger", main="fries")  these are being assigned to kwargs?I mean we have not written wrapper(side="burger", main="fries") ??

Comment: Yes, you *have* written `wrapper(side="burger", main="fries")`, because you have `@shout; def order(...)` as I said in my previous comment.